# Cloud Formation AWS::Cognito::UserPoolUser temporary password

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

I'm creating Cognito user using Cloud Formation template for Kibana cognito authentication. How to provide temporary password in the template?

Answer (score 1):

Far as I know, you can't do this via **AWS::Cognito::UserPoolUser** which I believe you are using.

Set up a password policy in the UserPool creation and it should do the job.

```
Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
  DeletionPolicy: Retain
  Properties:
    UserPoolName: UserPoolName
    AdminCreateUserConfig:
      AllowAdminCreateUserOnly: true
    Policies:
      PasswordPolicy:
        MinimumLength: 16
        RequireLowercase: true
        RequireNumbers: true
```

Comment: Hey, this is a password policy applicable for the all the users in the pool. What I need is create a user via Cloudformation, with user name and password which is complaint to this password policy

Comment: I don't think's an option for you to set up the temp password. If the policy is set, it should automatically create the password for the user.
For user creation, you can follow the documentation. -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpooluser.html

Comment: thanks. Will it generate password automatically ? If so how do I can see the generated password? I think then password policy is optional to generate a default password

Comment: It should be sent to you via the email provided. I've never done that myself, but it should follow the same steps in a manual user creation